# is this good way to access getContext() | requireContext() method each time in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, performance-testing, android-context

I generally prefer to use one *Context object* and assign value by using **getContext()** or **requireContext()** method only once while initializing object inside any *Fragment*.

I just wanted to know that is this right approach and it utilize less resource for better coding?
Another approach is to use **getContext()** or **requireContext()** each time while required inside any *Fragment*.

Let me attach one of my code snippet.

```
private lateinit var mContext: Context    // Declaring lateinit context 
...
...
mContext = requireContext()    // Initialization of lateinit context
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your context lives as long as the fragment lives. Therefore, the call to the `requireContext()` always returns the context instance of the current fragment. Answering your question - using the `requireContext()` is the most correct way to refer to the context.

There is one more `requireActivity()` method, that is needed to get the activity of this fragment.

Be careful when creating references to objects returned by these methods.

For example,
`private val context = requireContext()`

creating such a reference in a instance of a class that is outside of your fragment will lead to a memory leak.

If you still need to pass the context inside any class outside the fragment, then use WeakReference or applicationContext to prevent a memory leak.